How to Set Up Individual Bash History Files for Each Container Alongside a Unified History File?
In my current setup, all of my bash histories are stored in a single file, which is pointed to HISTFILE.
This history includes a history of the host system and all containers.
Along with this history, I want to set up per container bash_history_<cont_name>.
Setup Details:

The host system has a docker containers setup.
All containers have /home/uname/ shared with the host. (.bashrc is also shared)
All command history [ of host & all containers ] is written to HISTFILE.
For quick updates to HISTFILE, the prompt is updated in .bashrc in the following way.

PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND$'\n'}history -a; history -c; history -r"

Along with this system in place. I also want to save the history of commands used in containers to file dedicated to that container only.
Ex. For containers ContA & ContB, the command history will be saved to common 'HISTFILE', as well as command history of respective containers should also be updated. For ContA, ~/bash_history_ContA should also be updated.
P.S.: The single file command history is updated as soon as the command is executed.
The bash_history_<cont_name> per container could be a lazy updated file.

What containers? Please [edit] your question and give us more details about your setup. It is relatively easy to have a script that changes your HISTFILE depending on something, for example on the hostname so you can have different histories on different hostnames even if you share the same $HOME on all of them, but we need to know what we can use to know we need to switch in your case.

For the "The single file command history is updated as soon as the command is executed", you can do this with one of the 3 answers to this question (test the one that works best for you)
In the PROMPT_COMMAND you can also add any redirection to whatever global file you wish : just add the latest command to it before each prompt ? (careful : some may be multiline)
